# how to build keras model on Bert output with different shapes

Tags: tensorflow, keras, model, nlp, bert-language-model

i'm trying to build classifier for my study using bert and keras.

i got bert encoding (shape - (1,X,768)) when X is the number of words and spaces in the sentence.

how can i build keras model if X is not consistent?

Comment: The simplest way is to pad your sentences to the fixed length - the longest sentence in your dataset.

Comment: thank you, is the cls encoding will do the work for classification?
does it represent the whole sentence?

Comment: Yes, it will works for classification. If in your dataset the longest sequence will have 10 tokens, then for shorter sentences for example "I have a dog" the representation will be ["I", "have", "a", "dog", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] but when you put for prediction sentence longer than 10, the sentence will be cutted into first 10 tokens.

Comment: Great, thanx.
which way will give better results?
1.use the cls encoding from bert
2. pad the sentence with 0 as you describe?